# Position text element at left side of parent svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, transform, positioning

Inside my `SVG` elment is a `g` element which contains several `rect`, `circle` & `text` nodes.

```
<svg id="familyTreeSvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="familyTreeSvgG" transform="translate(-3640.998879446216,-3805.319191946216) scale(1)">
        <rect class="lifeline" x="3999.329665532318" y="3911.819191946216" width="441.67051879637665" height="20"
              rx="10"
              ry="10" id="lifelineRectSamanthaBishopI10" style="fill: red; opacity: 1;"></rect>
        <rect class="lifeline" x="3981.819191946216" y="3986.819191946216" width="459.1809923824785" height="40" rx="10"
              ry="10" id="lifelineRectOliverLionI1" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 1;"></rect>

        <g class="name">
            <text x="4006.819191946216" y="4011.819191946216" style="fill-opacity: 1;">Oliver Lion</text>
        </g>
        <g class="name">
            <text x="4024.329665532318" y="3926.819191946216" style="fill-opacity: 1;">Samantha Bishop</text>
        </g>

        <g class="node M" id="rootNode" transform="translate(3991.819191946216,4006.819191946216)">
            <circle class="node" r="20" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle>
        </g>
        <g class="node F" id="SamanthaBishopI10" transform="translate(4009.32958984375, 3921.819091796875)">
            <circle class="node" r="13" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

[image]

I use `D3js` to zoom and drag the `g`-element. 
When a name (`text`-element) would `translate` outside the left side I want it to stick to the left side rather than translating to the left, so that the name is still visible.

My current attempt is:

```
function movePersonNames(person, lifeLine) { 
    let boundingBox = lifeLine.getBoundingClientRect();
    let lifeLineWidth = boundingBox.width;
    let lifeLineCoordinate =  boundingBox.x;
    let lifeLineVisible = lifeLineWidth + lifeLineCoordinate;
    if (lifeLineCoordinate < 0 && lifeLineVisible > 0) {
        let moveText = "translate(" + lifeLineCoordinate * -1 + ",0)";
        d3.select(person).attr("transform", moveText);
    }
}
```

but than some names are still partly invisible, while others are too far away:

[image]

It's even worse when the scale is not 1.

I also tried to use the inverted `d3.event.transform.x`:

```
    d3.select(person).attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.transform.x * -1 + ",0)");
```

but than all the names jump too far and are no longer visible.

That's how i want it:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Is there some missing css?

Comment: yes, but i didn't think that css would be necessary. But i can add it if needed.

Comment: Have a read of this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then edit the question.

Comment: Do you have an image with the desired result?

Comment: @enxaneta i added a image of the desired result.